# Parsing an XML inside a zip in-memory

Tags: java, xml, dom, zip

I have a Zip that contains two files: an XML and a thumbnail. I would like to open the XML file and parse it WITHOUT having to extract on disk.

One of DocumentBuilder's parse method requires an InputStream. Is there a way to get the InputStream of the XML in the Zipped file? I kinda got lost. I'm pretty sure ZipInputStream or ZipFile has something to offer, but I can't figure it out :/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("your.zip");
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
ZipEntry ze = null;
while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (ze.getName().equals("your.xml")) {
        // pass zin to DocumentBuilder
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the awful mistake of returning the InputStream to another method that contained the parsing algorithm. So the stream was already closed before it was parsed :/

Answer (score 0):

There are some input stream classes in [java.util.zip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html), not sure if they help, but it looks promising, especially [ZipInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).